# Use on change event to keep multiple inputs in the desired range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a form that allows users to set a grading scale to be applied to test templates. This form has a number input for A,B,C,D,F. I'm trying to use javascript (jquery) to keep each of the numbers in the appropriate order.

**In the fiddle I changed to html inputs so I could easily make use of js fiddle, that part shouldn't matter**

What I have so far is working somewhat however, it is still possible to send a value above or below the set value for another grade level. What I'd like is to increment the other grade letter value to disallow this overlap. Please let me know if you need more clarification.

Here is the **html** for the inputs:

```
  <div class="form-group" style="width:500px;">
      @Html.LabelFor(a => a.GradeScale, "Enter the number values for the grade scale")
      <div>
        <span class="large-text">A</span> @Html.TextBox("ARange", 100, "", new { @id = "aRange", @type = "number", @class = "thin-column", @max = 100, @min = 4 })
        to <span id="aLowRange">94</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="large-text">B</span> @Html.TextBox("BRange", 93, "", new { @id = "bRange", @type = "number", @class = "thin-column", @max = 99, @min = 3 })
        to <span id="bLowRange">85</span>
      </div>
      <span class="large-text">C</span> @Html.TextBox("CRange", 84, "", new { @id = "cRange", @type = "number", @class = "thin-column", @max = 98, @min = 2 })
        to <span id="cLowRange">77</span>
      <div>
        <span class="large-text">D</span> @Html.TextBox("DRange", 76, "", new { @id = "dRange", @type = "number", @class = "thin-column", @max = 97, @min = 1 })
        to <span id="dLowRange">70</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span class="large-text">F</span> @Html.TextBox("FRange", 69, "", new { @id = "fRange", @type = "number", @class = "thin-column", @max = 96, @min = 0 })
        to <span id="fLowRange">0</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

here is the javascript I've written:

```
$(function () {
  $('#aRange,#bRange,#cRange,#dRange,#fRange').on('change', function () {

var aLowRange = parseInt($('#bRange').val()) + 1;
$('#aLowRange').text(aLowRange);

var bLowRange = parseInt($('#cRange').val()) + 1;
$('#bLowRange').text(bLowRange);

var cLowRange = parseInt($('#dRange').val()) + 1;
$('#cLowRange').text(cLowRange);

var dLowRange = parseInt($('#fRange').val()) + 1;
$('#dLowRange').text(dLowRange);

//check to see if the low val is higher than the high val then correct
$('#bRange').val() >= parseInt($('#bLowRange').val()) ? $('#bLowRange').text(parseInt($('#bLowRange').val()) + 1) : "";
$('#cRange').val() >= parseInt($('#cLowRange').val()) ? $('#cLowRange').text(parseInt($('#cLowRange').val()) + 1) : "";
$('#dRange').val() >= parseInt($('#dLowRange').val()) ? $('#dLowRange').text(parseInt($('#dLowRange').val()) + 1) : "";
$('#fRange').val() >= parseInt($('#fLowRange').val()) ? $('#fLowRange').text(parseInt($('#fLowRange').val()) + 1) : "";

});
});
```

and here is a fiddle showing what I have so far in action. I'm open to javascript or jquery assistance:

https://jsfiddle.net/jacobrutter/nub2gsoL/

I don't need a complete solution, if you can point me in the right direction I'll run with it. **Thanks!**

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding this, but you don't need any JS for this if you have the max and min set to the appropriate grade levels you want. https://jsfiddle.net/06xyg194/

Comment: @Keith I'm hoping to allow teachers flexibility to make the grade scale flexible. In theory they could create A range from 100-5, B 4-3, C 3-2, D 2-1, F 0. And on the other side they could make A range 100-99, B range 98-97, C range 96-95, D range 94-93, F range 92-0. 
Probably they wont, but I'm looking for that kind of flexibility.

Comment: so then the aLowRange... should be input's so they can change it correct?

Comment: I think you just want to check your values in your change function.  If it overlaps one of the adjacent ones, then just use javascript to set the value back to the value before the overlap.  You could just write a function that loops through them all and makes sure they don't overlap, and then just run that function every time a value is changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to jsfiddle solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/cmurk0zh/

helper functions:

```
function findIndex(value, array) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].letter === value) {
        return i;
    }
  }
}

var gradeValues = [
  {
    letter: 'a',
    max: 100,
    min: 94
  },
  {
    letter: 'b',
    max: 100,
    min: 94
  },
  {
    letter: 'c',
    max: 100,
    min: 94
  },
  {
    letter: 'd',
    max: 100,
    min: 94
  },
  {
    letter: 'f',
    max: 100,
    min: 94
  },

];

function setMaxInputValue(thisGrade) {
      $('#' + thisGrade.letter + 'Range').val(thisGrade.max);
}
function setMinLabelText(thisGrade) {
      $('#' + thisGrade.letter + 'LowRange').text(thisGrade.min);
}
```

on change:

```
$(function () {
  //when an input val changes, adjust the low range appropriately
  $('#aRange,#bRange,#cRange,#dRange,#fRange').on('change', function (event) {

    var changedValueId = event.currentTarget.id;
    var startIndex = findIndex(changedValueId[0], gradeValues);

    // get values
    for (var i = 0; i < gradeValues.length; i++ ) {
        gradeValues[i].max = parseInt($('#' + gradeValues[i].letter + 'Range').val());
      gradeValues[i].min = $('#' + gradeValues[i].letter + 'LowRange').text();
    }

    // Correct same
    var thisGrade = gradeValues[startIndex];
    if (thisGrade.min >= thisGrade.max) {
        thisGrade.min = thisGrade.max - 1;
      setMaxInputValue(thisGrade);
      setMinLabelText(thisGrade);
    }
    // correct above
    for (var i = startIndex; i > 0; i--) {
        var previousGradeValue = gradeValues[i-1];
        previousGradeValue.min = gradeValues[i].max + 1;
      setMinLabelText(previousGradeValue);
      if (previousGradeValue.max <= previousGradeValue.min) {
        previousGradeValue.max = previousGradeValue.min + 1;
        setMaxInputValue(previousGradeValue);
      }
    }

    // correct below
        for (var i = startIndex; i < gradeValues.length - 1; i++) {
        var nextGradeValue = gradeValues[i+1];
        nextGradeValue.max = gradeValues[i].min - 1;
      setMaxInputValue(nextGradeValue);
      if (nextGradeValue.max <= nextGradeValue.min) {
        nextGradeValue.min = nextGradeValue.max - 1;
        setMinLabelText(nextGradeValue);
      }
    }

    });
});
```

I parameterized some of the variables so that it could be iterated through. The main thing about this solution, is that it finds which one was changed and modifies the values above and below.

This solution does not have full bound checking at beginning and end values.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I'll add the bound checking.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is the javascript I put together that solves my use case but isn't very DRY. I think I'll use it and circle back later to refactor.

```
$(function () {
//when an input val changes, adjust the low range appropriately
$('#aRange,#bRange,#cRange,#dRange,#fRange').on('change', function () {

var aRange = parseInt($('#aRange').val());
var bRange = parseInt($('#bRange').val());
var cRange = parseInt($('#cRange').val());
var dRange = parseInt($('#dRange').val());
var fRange = parseInt($('#fRange').val());

var aLowRange = parseInt($('#bRange').val()) + 1;
$('#aLowRange').text(aLowRange);

var bLowRange = parseInt($('#cRange').val()) + 1;
$('#bLowRange').text(bLowRange);

var cLowRange = parseInt($('#dRange').val()) + 1;
$('#cLowRange').text(cLowRange);

var dLowRange = parseInt($('#fRange').val()) + 1;
$('#dLowRange').text(dLowRange);

//check to see one grade value crosses another then correct
  var rangeArray = [aRange, bRange, cRange, dRange, fRange];
var nameArray = ['aRange', 'bRange', 'cRange', 'dRange', 'fRange'];
var lowNameArray = ['aLowRange', 'bLowRange', 'cLowRange', 'dLowRange', 'fLowRange'];

  for (var i = 0; i < rangeArray.length; i++) {
    if (rangeArray[i] <= rangeArray[i + 1]) {

       rangeArray[i + 1] -= 1;
       $('#' + nameArray[i + 1]).val(rangeArray[i + 1]);
       var lowRange = parseInt($('#' + nameArray[i + 1]).val()) + 1;
       $('#' + lowNameArray[i]).text(lowRange);
     }
   }
 });
});
```

Thank you for taking a moment to discuss it with me, it helped me think about the problem in different ways. (I'm open to improvements, if you do improve upon it, I'll happily mark yours as answer.)